# Python Tkinter Tabs and Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Objective: 
I am trying to create a GUI with a portion of the screen having "tabs" (information displayed can be changed based on selected tab), and another portion constantly displaying the same thing.

```
import ttk
import Tkinter


def demo():
    #root = tk.Tk()
    schedGraphics = Tkinter
    root = schedGraphics.Tk()


    root.title("Testing Bot")
    universal_height = 606
    canvas = schedGraphics.Canvas(root,width = 900, height = universal_height)

    nb = ttk.Notebook(root)


    # adding Frames as pages for the ttk.Notebook
    # first page, which would get widgets gridded into it
    page1 = ttk.Frame(nb,width = 300,height = universal_height)
    # second page
    page2 = ttk.Frame(nb,width = 300,height = universal_height)


    nb.add(page1, text='One')
    nb.add(page2, text='Two')

    #

    nb.grid()

    day_label = schedGraphics.Label(page1, text="Day1:")
    day_label.pack()
    day_label.place(x=0, y=30)

    day_label = schedGraphics.Label(page2, text="Day2:")
    day_label.pack()
    day_label.place(x=0, y=30)


    canvas.create_rectangle(50,500,300,600,fill = "red")
    canvas.grid()



    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo()
```

Problems:

1. In the current configuration the tabs are located in the MIDDLE of the screen not on the left side.
2. If I change canvas.grid() to canvas.pack() it doesn't actually open any window?
3. The rectangle on canvas does not appear!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. To do this, when gridding your notebook, pass the argument `column` and choose 0, so that it will be located at the far left, like this:

   `nb.grid(column=0)`
2. That's because you have to chose, for your tkinter app, between `.grid()` and `.pack()`: the two are not compatible. As you used `.grid()` before, the window won't open and a `TclError` pops up.
3. Your canvas is in fact hidden under the notebook. To fix that, set the `row` argument when using `grid` to 0, so that it is at the top, like this:

   `canvas.grid(column=1, row=0)`

Final code:

```
import Tkinter
import ttk


def demo():
    #root = tk.Tk()
    schedGraphics = Tkinter
    root = schedGraphics.Tk()

    root.title("Testing Bot")
    universal_height = 606

    nb = ttk.Notebook(root)

    # adding Frames as pages for the ttk.Notebook
    # first page, which would get widgets gridded into it
    page1 = ttk.Frame(nb, width= 300,height = universal_height)
    # second page
    page2 = ttk.Frame(nb,width = 300,height = universal_height)

    nb.add(page1, text='One')
    nb.add(page2, text='Two')

    nb.grid(column=0)

    day_label = schedGraphics.Label(page1, text="Day1:")
    day_label.pack()
    day_label.place(x=0, y=30)

    day_label = schedGraphics.Label(page2, text="Day2:")
    day_label.pack()
    day_label.place(x=0, y=30)

    canvas = schedGraphics.Canvas(root, width=900, height=universal_height)
    canvas.create_rectangle(50, 500, 300, 600, fill="red")
    canvas.grid(column=1, row=0)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo()
```

I hope this helps !

Comment: Point #1 is misleading. For one, you say to use column 0, but show using column 1. Second, just because it's in the left-most column won't guarantee it's against the left edge of the window.

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry for that typo, thanks for pointing it out. For the second point, by far left I mean that nothing will be between the notebook and the edge, but not necessarily that it would be stuck to it.

Comment: Thank you @TrakJohnson! perfect answer and does exactly what I wanted. Follow up question: suppose I wanted a rectangle draw ON the tab (and one that I would be able to drag onto the canvas). I already have the drag code working on the canvas, but I can't get any rectangles to draw on the "tab"

Comment: I believe that this is not possible, as rectangles and shapes can only be drawn and manipulated inside a canvas. One solution to this would be to create another canvas inside the tab, but I'm not sure how you would transfer it from one canvas to another. Maybe you can detect when the mouse is on the edge of the canvas inside the tabs, delete that rectangle and make it appear on the main canvas.